# populate combobox with datatable select query

Tags: c#, combobox, datatable, dataset

I have a datatable which contains a list of clients, this is then assigned to the datasource of a combobox.

I then have another datatable that contains a list of clients sites, when the combobox is changed it should perform a select on the sites datatable and return only rows that match and fill the sites combobox.

Issue is it returns System.Data.DataRow instead of the data contained in the sitename column!

```
public frmTechSupportCall()
{
    cboxClientName.DataSource = parentfrm._ClientsList;
    cboxClientName.DisplayMember = "companyname";
    cboxClientName.ValueMember = "client_id";
    cboxClientName.SelectedIndex = 1;
    cboxClientName.Refresh();
}
private void cboxClientName_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //var temp = cboxClientName.SelectedValue;            

    if (cboxClientName.SelectedValue.GetType().ToString() == "System.Int32")
    {
        //DataRow[] dr = parentfrm._ClientsSites.Select(@"client_id = " + cboxClientName.SelectedValue);                
        cboxClientSite.DisplayMember = "sitename";
        cboxClientSite.ValueMember = "site_id";
        cboxClientSite.DataSource = parentfrm._ClientsSites.Select(@"client_id = " + cboxClientName.SelectedValue);
        //cboxClientSite.BindingContext = this.BindingContext;
        //_ClientsList.Rows.InsertAt(drow, 0);
        //cboxClientSite.Items.Add(new object[] { 0, "--Please Select --" });
        //cboxClientSite.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: DJ Kraze please read the question fully it states the combox returns System.Data.DataRow instead of the data!!

Comment: that's not a question now is it Neo what you have stated is `he combox returns System.Data.DataRow instead of the data!` that's not a question

Comment: @Neo much more like it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do it like this

```
cboxClientSite.DataSource = parentfrm._ClientsSites.Select(@"client_id = " + cboxClientName.SelectedValue).CopyToDataTable();
```

Comment: Error 79 'System.Array' does not contain a definition for 'ToDataTable' and no extension method 'ToDataTable' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Array' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @Neo typing mistake it is copytodatatable, i have updated

Comment: This one fixed the issue, I've edited the code to show the full syntax

Comment: @Neo your issue is resolved?